# dplyr count without qoutes

Tags: r, shiny, dplyr

I wondering why dplyr produce this to two differents outputs

```
df <- data.frame("A" = 1:10, "B" = 1:10, "C" = 1:10)    
df %>% select("A") %>%  count("A")
# A tibble: 1 x 2
  `"A"`     n
  <chr> <int>
1 A        10


df %>% select(A) %>%  count(A)
# A tibble: 10 x 2
       A     n
   <int> <int>
 1     1     1
 2     2     1
 3     3     1
 4     4     1
 5     5     1
 6     6     1
 7     7     1
 8     8     1
 9     9     1
10    10     1
```

In this case I need the second one. I´m building a shiny app that takes the names with a

```
selectInput("variables", 
                  choices = names(df), 
                  selected = "A", 
                  multiple = TRUE)
```

and then use this input to create a summary table with `df %>% select(input$variables) %>% count(input$variables)` but the result is the first output.

Comment: you can refer https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html

Answer (score 1):

With the latest version of `dplyr` (>0.7) you should use the new tidyeval syntax.

```
# varname <- input$variables
varname <- "A"
df %>% select(!!as.name(varname)) %>%  count(!!as.name(varname))
```